# How to ristrict SharePoint API permission to a specific site

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-security

How to restrict the SharePoint API permission to a specific site. I can see there is a a permission called ***Sites.Selected*** but there is no option to select the site. Do I need to select it at the code level or can we select it from the portal?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

To **restrict the SharePoint API permission to a specific site,** I used the below PowerShell script:

```bash
$siteUrl = “https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testruk”
$clientId = “AppClientID” 
$certThumbprint = “Thumbprint” 
$tenant = “xxx.onmicrosoft.com”

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
$writeperm = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions “Write” -Site $siteUrl -AppId $clientId -DisplayName “PowerShell-SharepointOnline”
$PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity $clientId
Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteurl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions “FullControl”
```

[image]

Now, **I tried to connect to the SharePoint site and I am able to access it successfully** like below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
Get-PnPList
```

[image]

When I tried to **access another SharePoint site, I got the error** like below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
Get-PnPList
```

[image]

You can also make use of **Graph API query** like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/permissions

Content-Type: application/json
{

  "roles": ["write"],

  "grantedToIdentities": [{

    "application": {

      "id": "APPID",

      "displayName": "APPName"

    }

  }]

}
```

**Reference:**

[Controlling app access on a specific SharePoint site  - Microsoft Graph](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/)

Comment: Thanks, can we use client secret instead of certificate Thumbprint. Also, PowerShell is not recognizing Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission. Which version of SharepointPNPPowershellOnline are you using? thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can make use of [**ClientSecret**](https://i.imgur.com/qXd4ZDr.png) to execute the script and check this for [**Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission**](https://i.imgur.com/QBodkBO.png).

Comment: Thanks, one more question -  Sites.Selected should be used from Microsoft Graph or from SharePoint?

Comment: It should be SharePoint permission

Comment: I have registered an App in Azure, and granted it `Sites.Selected` permissions (Application) in the `API Permissions` area in Azure, and when I run this command:  `Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive`, and then login with my admin account, I get a prompt for around 50 extremely high permissions, including Full Control access on all sites.  I have no idea why this is happening just from using `Connect-PnPOnline`, and I can't find any documentation or forum posts about this undesired behaviour - why is it asking for GOD access immediately after entering `Connect-PnPOnline`?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a new feature, the only way to actually "select" the sites for which the permissions apply is through a Microsoft Graph Rest API call.

You'll find a nice article here [Devblog Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/) and the official document [Microsoft Graph Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0).

I haven't use this API yet though, so I can't give you more detailled instructions.

Comment: There are other ways, i.e https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html and https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html, eg:  [here](https://www.extendm365.com/2022/04/how-to-give-app-access-on-specific.html).  I looked into using Microsoft Graph to specify the sites the app would have permission to via `Sites.Selected`, but it seems to involve having *another* App registration with full control access, so that *it* has the permissions to grant those permissions.  That hurt my brain and I stopped looking into that option.