# Granting an API service account access to specific Microsoft Office365 documents?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

How can I grant an API service account access to specific Microsoft Office365 documents?

Specifically, I would like to write a script which has read access to one specific Excel document.

In Google Cloud, this would be done by creating a service account, then sharing the document with the service account's email.

What's the equivalent in the Microsoft stack?

Comment: Where is the document stored? SharePoint? Onedrive? Probably just need a bit more context.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I'm still new to the Microsoft stack and didn't realize there was a difference. And to answer your question: the document is stored in Sharepoint, but can be moved to OneDrive if that would be easier.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742965/how-to-ristrict-sharepoint-api-permission-to-a-specific-site/75754458#75754458?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Rukmini! I'm not sure how I would use it, though, as I'd like to restrict access to a single document.